# Transparent frameset in iframe ie white background

Tags: html, iframe, internet-explorer, transparent, frames

I'm trying to nest a frameset in an iframe and I can't get the background of the frameset to show as transparent in IE. Firefox displays correctly.

Here's the iframe:

```
<iframe src="frameset.html" name="myframe" width="500" height="500" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

And this is
Frameset.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>

<frameset cols="21%,*" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="no">
<frame name="menu" src="test.html" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="noresize" frameborder="no" style="background: transparent" allowtransparency="true">
<frame name="main" src="test.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="noresize" frameborder="no" style="background: transparent" allowtransparency="true">
</frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried giving the `frameset` a `background-color: transparent`?

Comment: unless you've got a serious reason not to, almost all of your frame attributes should be move to css files or at the very least style tags. in which case you would use style="background-color: transparent" for transparency.

Comment: I've tried all of that. If I remove the frameset from the frameset.html document the transparency works. The issue is with the frameset itself.

Comment: have you ever found a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still no one has any sort of answer... except that IE is so utterly broken as a browser engine. Even today with IE8 and IE9 coming out soon. I hate IE. I wish all users would dump it for a real browser like Firefox or Opera.

Comment: 8 years later, IE still sucks.

Answer (score 5):

I've recently learned that IE browswers have a non-standard code for iframes: allowTransparency="true"

Put this in your iframe and set the style background to transparent and you should be fine.

Comment: Brilliant - this fixes the same issue I had in IE8